# Radar Shadow for Sentinel 1 images in GEE?

Tags: google-earth-engine

Is there a way to mask out areas of radar shadow in GEE? This should be produced during pre-processing I believe but I can't find a layer to add that would let me mask out the shadowed areas for Sentinel 1 in GEE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script does terrain flattening, and adds layover and shadow bands:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/f4b43be1795bc1a689f7a3e1998d287b

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you! I have a few questions on this code. Doesn't GEE preprocessing already do border removal - which if I am reading this right is one of the functions in here? Are you doing more removal on the borders?

Comment: I also have been using STEP as well and have been a little confused about Gamma, Beta, and Alpha returns. Are the intensities returned by this function still the same intensities or have they been converted into Gamma or Beta?

Comment: There used to be noise around the borders, that's why I started masking them out. Maybe the images have been re-processed since last I tried. Try to leave the border masking out and check how it look for your AOI.

On the Gamma etc. Sorry, I don't know. I'm not a radar expert unfortunately.